# Airflow 2.0 Docker Setup with Local Executor

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am fairly new to Airflow and Docker environments. Yet, I need to setup the Airflow 2.0 as a Docker with Local Executor. I have found many resources such as the following:
http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/start/docker.html

But all refer to the Celery Executor setup.
In need for the Local Executor setup and the creation of the docker-compose.yaml files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A fairly popular docker-compose for LocalExecutor can be found here: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml

You would run using:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml up
```